# Get columns from array VBA

Tags: arrays, vba, excel, variant

I'm having difficulty returning a set of columns from an array.  I've returned an sql select statement to my variant array.  It has 16 columns.  I need to grab 12 of the 16 columns to return to my spreadsheet from a specific row in the array. I'm using this code to get my row:

```
    If UBound(Filter(budget, Cells(i, 1).Value, , vbBinaryCompare)) >= 0 And Cells(i, 1).Value <> "" Then
```

How do I then get just the 12 columns I need?  The columns are the final 12 columns in the array and will always be in the order I need them.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: This begs the question, why are you returning 16 columns when you only need 12?

Comment: a couple of reasons: I'm grouping by one of the columns my my sql statement, and I am using the other three columns to return aggregated data in other locations of the tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's going to depend on the shape of the array.
If it's a one dimension array

```
 a = Filter(Selection, Cells(i, 1).Value, , vbTextCompare)
 rows = UBound(a)
 Cells(i, 1).Resize(1, rows ) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(a)
```

*Notice that WorksheetFunction.Transpose(a) swaps the rows and columns of the array.*

Multi-dimensional arrays will depend on how they where created.

We can think of it like this

> Database Query Arrays: a = recordset.getRows()

And

> Dim a(10, 100)  Redim Preserve a(10, Ubound(a) + 1)

Are aligned like this a(columns, rows) because you can only re-size the last dimentsion of an array.
**So we would:**
     a = Filter(Selection, Cells(i, 1).Value, , vbTextCompare)
     rows = UBound(a, 2)
     columns = UBound(a, 1)
     Cells(i, 1).Resize(columns, rows ) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(a)

Excel Range Arrays are base 1 and have the same shape as the Range itself.

```
a = Range("A1:K200").Value
a(1,1) = cells(1, 1) evaluates to True
```

So you can do this

```
a = Range("A1:K200").Value
Range("A1:K200") = a
```

Or
     a = Filter(Selection, Cells(i, 1).Value, , vbTextCompare)
     rows = UBound(a, 1)
     columns = UBound(a, 2)
     Cells(i, 1).Resize(rows, columns) = a

Comment: ahhhh transposing is a great idea, I hadn't even though of that. thank you!